# How can I duplicate the app for other uses?

Tags: android

I am currently developing an Android app for my company's products.

For a forthcoming meeting, I need to create a demonstration version with added functionality to existing applications. I want to keep both applications on my smartphone because I need to compare the existing application with the demo version in the meeting.

I noticed that simply duplicating the project does not create two applications on the smartphone.

Please tell me what I need to change in my cloned project to have two applications on my smartphone.

Comment: I haven't used it, but our organization uses [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/) for having different versions available on the same phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in package name does the magic. or you can also use the android flavours
go [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Answer (score 0):

change the package name of the app is what you need since your phone uses that to identify the app on your phone.

Comment: The same answer has already been given.

Comment: We answered only seconds apart.

Comment: 1 minute, to be exact.

Comment: While He was answering, I was answering and was looking on quora since the same question was posted over there. I took a look at the correct answer which was to change the package name. By the time I typed the answer 5 minutes had passed  since I clicked the add answer button.

Comment: But now does it make sense to keep to same answers? The other one has already been accepted. And also liked.

Comment: Okay delete this answer..

Comment: I can't. But you can.

Comment: I cant either only lets me edit, I might not have enough points to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Flavors is the best solution in my opinion.